# LLamada a Función en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de resolver un problema en JavaScript que requiere de usar `Closures`, pero estoy confundido con una de las llamadas a la función que muestro a continuación:

```
addTogether(2)(3)
```

Mi pregunta es; Se puede invocar en JavaScript una función de esta forma ? Si esto es valido como recibiré los argumentos?

Agredecere mucho cualquier aclaración.

Comment: puedes mostrar la funcion completa porfavor

Answer (score 1):

he logrado resolverlo y lo dejare por aqui en caso de que alguien le sirva...

```
function creaSumador(x) {
  return function(y) {
    if(typeof(y)!=="number"){
      return undefined;
    }else{
      return x + y;     
    }

  };
}


function addTogether() {
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  if(args.length>1){
    if(typeof(args[0])!=="number" || typeof(args[1])!=="number"){
      return undefined;
    }else{
      return args[0]+args[1];
    }
  }else{
    if(!isNaN(args[0])){
      var sumaX = creaSumador(args[0]);
      return sumaX;
    }else{
      return undefined;
    }

  }
}

addTogether(2)(3);
```

La funcion addTogether solo recibe como argumentos lo que contiene el primer par de parentesis, con esto el Closure crea la funcion que sumara el valor recibido. Al crear la funcion con , al final solo envío como respuesta la variable que almacena la funcion, la que al ser retornada al punto de llamada utiliza como argumento lo contenido en el segundo par de parentesis. Espero que pueda servirle a alguien que se enfrente al mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo un ejemplo comentado de como funciona un clousure

```js
function creaSumador(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  };
}

let var1 = creaSumador(2);
//var1 es una funcion que contiene la variable 'x' y que necesita un valor y 
let valor = var1(3);
// la variable valor contiene el valor(ya no una funcion)
console.log(valor);
```